# Finding the AUID for Apple Maps in order to scrape locations

Tags: web-scraping, apple-maps

I'm under the impression that the AUID is needed to retrieve location information for location listings and etc. on Apple Maps.  Is there a known way to retrieve this id or are we waiting for Apple to publicly release a web version of Apple Maps?  Fruitymaps would have been a great alternative were it still functional.