# Is there a way to retrieve auid of location for apple map venues?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-maps

I want to open apple map for specific location/venue and to do so I'm doing

```
 if let url = URL(string: "maps://?address=Railway%20Station%20Area,%20Surat,%20395003,%20Gujarat,%20India&auid=4338464186124767060&ll=21.205538,72.840954&lsp=9902&q=Surat%20Railway%20Station&t=m") {
     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
 }
```

[image]

I can open map using same latitude longitude, but it will only appear as simple annotation without any detail in location card of apple map

```
 if let url = URL(string: "maps://?ll=21.205538,72.840954&lsp=9902&q=Surat%20Railway%20Station&t=m") {
     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
 }
```

[image]

it turn out that only thing required for mapItem to appear as apple map defined item/venue is **auid** in URL

so if I use only this (ie. url only with auid), it will still open venue perfectly with all apple map associated details.

```
 if let url = URL(string: "maps://?auid=4338464186124767060") {
     UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
 }
```

so is there any way to fetch auid of venues for apple map?
can we get it using latitude & longitude?
Is there any other way to redirect venue to apple map with all the related info, not just simple annotation?

Comment: Identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45872553/finding-the-auid-for-apple-maps-in-order-to-scrape-locations

Comment: If you have the address and place details you should create a `MKPlacemark` and use that to create an `MKMapItem` and then you can [open maps with that item](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapitem/1452207-openmaps)

Comment: @Paulw11, I've tried that but it is also opening as simple annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
import MapKit

let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.3318, longitude: -122.0312)

let searchRequest = MKLocalSearch.Request()
searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "Apple Park"
searchRequest.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)

let search = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)

search.start { response, error in
    guard let mapItems = response?.mapItems, let firstItem = mapItems.first else {
        print("No results found")
        return
    }
    
    print("Name: \(firstItem.name ?? "")")
    print("Address: \(firstItem.placemark.title ?? "")")
    print("AUID: \(firstItem.pointOfInterestCategory?.rawValue ?? ""):\(firstItem.url?.lastPathComponent ?? "")")
}
```

Comment: firstItem.pointOfInterestCategory is nil, and firstItem.url is "https://www.apple.com"

Comment: That means the location you are searching for is not a recognized point of interest in the Apple Maps database you need to search for a place that is a recognized point of interest in the Apple Maps database. For example, you could search for "Golden Gate Park" in San Francisco, which is a recognized park in the Apple Maps database